# Can you use the FBSnapshottestcase library with Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I've got the [fbsnapshottestcase](https://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case) library and subclassed `FBSnapshotTestCase` in a test file I have in my iOS project. However if I try to call `FBSnapshotVerifyView` I get a method not found error.

Comment: It should be noted that FBSnapshotTest case supports Swift as of version 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today for a new project I started in swift. Also, I forked the repo to fix it. You'll find it there :

https://github.com/delannoyk/ios-snapshot-test-case

You can add it as a Pod:

```
 target "Tests" do
   pod 'FBSnapshotTestCase', :git => 'https://github.com/delannoyk/ios-snapshot-test-case'
 end
```

Comment: Could you show how to import the code for `FBSnapshotTestCase` into the test files? I get `Use of undeclared type FBSnapshotTestCase` errors in my test classes when I subclass `FBSnapshotTestCase`.

Comment: I added a bridging header file in the test target that contains this: 
`#import <FBSnapshotTestCase/FBSnapshotTestCase.h>`

Comment: Ah, that did it for me. Didn't realize I needed a bridging header for the test target, but it seems logical now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can make an extension and import it in bridge file:

FBSnapshotTestCase+SwiftAdditions.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FBSnapshotTestCase/FBSnapshotTestCase.h>

@interface FBSnapshotTestCase (SwiftAdditions)

- (void) snapshotVerifyView:(UIView *)view withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void) snapshotVerifyLayer:(CALayer *)layer withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end
```

FBSnapshotTestCase+SwiftAdditions.m:

```
#import "FBSnapshotTestCase+SwiftAdditions.h"

@implementation FBSnapshotTestCase (SwiftAdditions)

- (void) snapshotVerifyView:(UIView *)view withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    FBSnapshotVerifyView(view, identifier);
}

- (void) snapshotVerifyLayer:(CALayer *)layer withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    FBSnapshotVerifyLayer(layer, identifier);
}

@end
```

Comment: Saved me some time! Thanks